# July 2012 Moderator Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

***The Town Hall Chat took place on Friday, July 27th, at 14:00:00Z UTC / 10am EDT. A digest can be found [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/july-2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)***

Normally we try to schedule these at the start of the phase, but I may have... tripped over this one. As such, the Town Hall Chat will be a little delayed, but we'll still be holding one. Some have already voted, **keep in mind that you can change your election vote at any time**, so there's no harm in coming to the Town Hall Chat to either get reassurance for your choice, or to shift your decision.

Candidates have already been contacted and scheduling is being done.

Here are the details so far:

- Because of the delay in scheduling, we're shooting to schedule the event in the span of Thursday - Saturday (26th-28th). As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=webmasters.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Could it be scedualed thursday? Otherwise I will probably not be able to make it.

Comment: @Christofian I sent an email to the address listed on your account - if you could check that for a calendar link and specify when on Thursday, then I can set it up. Thursday is looking best but I need to know when in case your Thursday times don't line up